# how to show csv file data in table at reactjs

Tags: reactjs, csv, row, export-to-csv, show

i want to show csv data to table only specific column (1st and 2nd column)
but header name have space and when show data error having.Please can u tell me how to solve that error.... Thank you

want to show like that
[image]

My source code is below

test.csv

Test Data1,Test Data2,Test data3

AA,BB,CC

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Papa from "papaparse";

export default function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Papa.parse("/test.csv", {
      download: true,
      header: true,
      complete: data => {
        console.log(data.data);
        setRows(data);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>{rows?.meta.fields.map(column => <th>{column}</th>)}</tr>
        {rows?.data.map(row => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{row.Test Data1}</td>
              <td>{row.Test Data2}</td>
              <td>{row.Test Data3}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

console
[image]

error [image]

Comment: Hello can you show us your import part

Comment: import React, {Component} from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import * as Papa from 'papaparse';
import csvFile from "./INTAconnectionPCInfo.csv";

Comment: @antoineso  I also edit my question...Thank you

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` before `setRows(data)` and post your data format here

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Now i try to add header but one problem is Header name have space "Test Data1" and when insert value error having. Please can you tell me how to fix that. Now i change Question also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSV file, change the column names to `testData1`, `testData2`, ...

In your code, change the attributes accordingly:

```
<tr>
  <td>{row.testData1}</td>
  <td>{row.testData2}</td>
  <td>{row.testData3}</td>
</tr>
```

... or, keep the column names as they are and change the code to:

```
<tr>
  <td>{row['Test Data1']}</td>
  ...
</tr>
```